# Path Independence of Line Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

The Cauchy-Goursat theorem states that if a function $f$ is analytic on, and in the interior of, a contour $C$ then: $$\int_{C} f(z) \hspace{1mm} dz = 0.$$

From here, a lot of lecture notes deduce the following.

Cor. Suppose $f$ is analytic on some simply connected region $A$. Then for any two points $a, b \in A$ we have that $$\int_{C} f(z) \hspace{1mm} dz$$ is independent of the contour $C$ in $A$ joining $a$ and $b$.

However, the 'proof' often only shows $$\int_{C_1} f(z) \hspace{1mm} dz = \int_{C_2} f(z) \hspace{1mm} dz.$$ when $C_1$ and $C_2$ are non-intersecting (because then $C := C_1\cup C_2$ is a closed contour). What is the best way to prove independence for all $C_1$ and $C_2$? I can 'see' that one can just pick a third contour $C_3$ which doesn't intersect either $C_1$ or $C_2$, and the proof follows from that. But how can I make the existence of $C_3$ rigorous without 'advanced machinery'?

Answer (score 1):

If $C_1$ and $C_2$ only intersect finitely many times then you can break them both up at each intersection point and use the fact that path integrals are additive with respect to concatenating paths. Then the statement reduces to the non-self-intersecting case. A limiting argument can be used to handle the possibility that they intersect countably many times, I think.

Comment: I also came up with this plan, but couldn't convince myself that a limiting argument would easily work? Obviously one really needs smoothness of the contour here... but not sure how to use this.

Comment: @Joey: okay, maybe I spoke too hastily; the argument I had in mind was for the case that the set of intersection points has a single accumulation point. It generalizes to finitely many accumulation points but if there are more than that we might need some kind of obnoxious transfinite induction to make this argument work. Easier to just prove Cauchy-Goursat for arbitrary contours at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two paths going from $a$ to $b$ and if $\gamma$ is the path $\gamma_1$ followed by the inverse path of $\gamma_2$ (usually, $\gamma$ is denoted by $\gamma_2^-\vee\gamma_1$, then $\gamma$ is a closed path and therefore $\oint_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$. But this is the same thing as asserting that$$\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)\,\mathrm dz.$$Whether the paths $\gamma_1$ or $\gamma_2$ intersect or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer José. I guess I am following a lecture with a non-standard definition of contour then. For us, the definition requires a contour to be a simple closed curve made up of finitely many smooth arcs.

Comment: Yep === that definition simplifies the proof, while obscuring the actual power of the theorem. As for "I can just pick another path $C_3$ ... that's not so easy, because you don't know a priori that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are not space-filling curves. (Proving they cannot be, if they are smooth except at finitely many points, requires some fancy stuff as well!)

Comment: Thanks, John -- that's what I was afraid of! So are we really just stuck at this point? The best bet is to just prove Cauchy-Goursat for closed contours without the self-intersection restriction?